# Is a radio call required when vacating an altitude after being given a discretionary descent?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications

When operating a flight under these conditions:

1. In the USA
2. Under the FAA jurisdiction
3. Given a descent with pilot's discretion by controller
4. Operating on an IFR flight plan

Is a radio call required when vacating the altitude that was occupied when given the discretionary descent?

Comment: Great question! I just [answered](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35116/12720) on the duplicate question, hope it gives you what you were looking for.